# Oozie get a variable from a file

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie, hue

As an action in a workflow, Im writing the output of a Hive `SELECT COUNT` command to a text file in our hdfs.

I need to make a decision in the workflow after this, based on the value in the output.

I'm using HUE to construct this workflow.

What I need to know is:

1. How to get this value as a variable, preferably not at the start of the workflow as it will be generated by the initial action.
2. The syntax in the oozie decision for this variable.

I've tried my best to piece together other answers to similar questions but there's a few blank spaces I hope to fill in.

I'll be so grateful for any guidance! Thanks!

Comment: Oozie has a `capture-output` flag. Not sure if that's what you want, or it applies to Hive actions. What if you wrote a Java application that used JDBC to Hive in order to capture this variable instead of writing to HDFS? I'm also curious how did you plan on reading that file from HDFS?

Comment: @cricket_007 Unfortunately you cannot capture the output of hive commands, hence the convoluted path of writing the output to a file. and yes I did look at the java route, but my company has a very awkward Kerberos setup that makes running jdbc connections to our clusters extremely painful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for the Java path and `capture-output`. Oozie supports the Kerberos delegation using credentials (https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_ActionAuthentication.html) so you should not need to authenticate within Java; just use a standard JDBC connection

Comment: Thanks for the comment, decided to go down the route of a shell script instead!

Answer (score 0):

We faced this kind of situation, in which we changed from Hive action to shell action.

We were authenticating using Kerberos and using Hive Server2 and passing the count from shell action to the next action.

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what we've now decided too. Thanks!